# nginx deny all is woking but allow a ip is not working

Tags: nginx

I have configured nginx with aws loadbalancer and all works good when I try to access my websites. I am trying to restrict access at nginx level. I need to allow access for particular ip and deny access for all, when I try this its not working. Deny all is working but allow/deny a particular ip don't work. I have tried changing the order of deny and allow but still no luck.

Below is my code

```
server {
    listen  8080;    
    server_name localhost;

    location /{
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
    #    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        satisfy all;
        deny all;
        allow 10.10.10.8;
        auth_basic "example.com intra";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd/example.com.htpasswd;
    }
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
[root@web sites-available]#
```

I need to allow and deny ip based on nginx level and not on load balancer level.

Comment: The access log will show you the IP address that Nginx is seeing in the request. If this request is via a load balancer, you may need to use the [realip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html).

Comment: realip module is enable already

Comment: output of nginx -V --> --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module

Comment: Yes, it's included in most Nginx distributions, but you still need to include statements in your configuration to use it.

Comment: so what should be my real ip , it should be loadbalancers ip or the ip which I need to block.

Comment: That was perfectly working , thanks Richard for help